# How to show gif animation inside Manipulation in the cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

This creates a manipulate object show two static plots,

```
pic1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
pic2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
CloudDeploy[Manipulate[pic, {pic, {pic1 -> "sine", pic2 -> "cosine"}}]]
```

[image]

Is it possible to replace the static images above with gif animations, so that it shows different gif animations as I select different buttons?

For example, I tried something like

```
pic1 = Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}], {n, 0, 2, 0.1}];
pic2 = Table[Plot[Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}], {n, 0, 2, 0.1}];

CloudDeploy[Manipulate[ExportForm[pic, "gif"], {pic, {pic1 -> "sine", pic2 -> "cosine"}}]]
```

but it doesn't work. This is what I get from the cloud

[image]